# How to filter with maven on only one property

Tags: maven, properties, filter, filtering, war

I want to filter with maven on only one property with maven-war-plugin

I have the properties:

- key1=value1
- key2=value2

And a file : index.html

- Hello ${key1} - ${key2}

Actual result after filtering:

- Hello value1 - value2

Expected result : I want to filter only on the property 'key1'

- Hello value1 - ${key2}

My pom.xml :

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <webResources>
            <resource>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
                <directory>${project.basedir}/src/main/webapp</directory>
            </resource>
        </webResources>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Please, help me.
Thanks you

Answer (score 2):

The obvious way is to remove `key2` from your properties file.  If that isn't an option, the filtering mechanism provides an escapeString (read more about it in the [resources:resources goal docs](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/resources-mojo.html)).  By default, this is a backslash.

The index.html file would include

```
Hello ${key1} - \${key2}
```

and the filtering should produce

```
Hello value1 - ${key2}
```

I haven't actually tried this with webResources, however I know it works with regular project resources.

Comment: I have a case where the escapeString and removing keys are both not an option (no control on the filtered files). This is a very bad limitation from the filtering system.